# Edge creation for every intersection point in QGIS

Tags: qgis, intersection, route

I have created a route network for a village. Now I need to create an edge (without dissolving) for every intersection.

[image]

This is the network I have created.

[image]

For example, I have marked some intersection points in red mark.
How can I get that using this or any other way? But I do not want to dissolve because if I dissolve the networks, I will lose every information for all lines.

---

[image]

Maybe I was not able to depict the question well.
Please have a look at this.
I have taken two single lines that overlap each other. Now, if I use the intersection (not line intersection), it will keep only the intersect part and remove other components. But I need both of the intersecting part (marked red) and the part I drew as green.

Answer (score 0):

In QGIS (3.28 RC used here) use Line Intersections via menu `Vector>Analysis Tools>Line Intersections.`

[image]

Comment: Should I use the same shp file for both the input and intersect layer?

Comment: yes. if that is what you have. you can go to virtual/temporary layer like above first to test it out.

Comment: Thank You.
But that is not what I wanted. I want something like an intersection. And it's only showing some points.

Comment: if you have postgres you can use pgrouting  https://docs.pgrouting.org/2.5/en/pgRouting-concepts.html shapefiles not good for edge routing

Comment: Thank you.

Will you please check my comment where I added an image?